# Find the $x$-intercept of the tangent line to $f(x,y)$. Use gradients.

Tags: calculus

Need to know if my solution is correct.
The function is $f(x,y) = e^x (xy^2) - 4e$

\begin{align}
P &= (1, -2), Q = (x, y) \\
PQ &= \langle x - 1, y + 2\rangle \\
\nabla f(1,-2) &= -4e \langle-2,1\rangle
\end{align}

Normal vector line is $\langle-2,1\rangle$.

Tangent line is : $-2(x-1) + 1(y + 2) = 0$.

$x$-intercept of the tangent line to $f(x,y)$ is $-2(x-1) + 2 = 0$.

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct. I just think that could add maybe a some details in your gradient calculation and also be a bit more explicit on the meaning of $P$ and the expression $PQ$ is a bit disturbing because it is not the product of $P$ and $Q$. And finally you could really give the answer to the problem : the $x$-intercept of tangent line to $f$ in $(1,-2)$ is $(2,0)$.

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}  \\ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} e^xy^2(x+1)  \\ 2e^xxy\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\nabla f(1,-2)=4e\begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$